# Read a full name by sscanf

Tags: c++, c

I'm using C++, but
I decided to parse the lines of a log file with `sscanf`. After reading each line, it should extract data and store them to variables.

```
string test = "[06/03/2013 18:15:23] INFO - Open [Johny Cage]";

int day, month, year, second, minute, hour;
char name[128];

int c = sscanf(test.c_str(), "[%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d] INFO - Open [%127[^\n]%c]",
               &day, &month, &year, &second, &minute, &hour, name);

if (c == 7)
{
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

I need read the name as `Johny Cage` (The name maybe has spaces) and store it to `name`, but the output is:

> Johny Cage]

The problem is the trailing `]`. How can I use `sscanf` which it doesn't read last `]` ?

Comment: Use `[^]]` instead of `[^\n]`.

Comment: @user315052: It fails, the program crashed!

Comment: `name[strlen(name) - 1] = 0;`

Comment: `[%127[^\n]%c]` means ignore a `[` then copy up to 127 characters up to, but not including a `\n`, then copy any character (i.e. the `\n`), then ignore a `]`. So this would copy basically anything, like `[Johny Cage + 3 = 5...` into the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[^]]` instead of `[^\n]`. Also, remove the `%c` at then end of your scan format string.

```
int c = sscanf(test.c_str(), "[%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d] INFO - Open [%127[^]]]",
               &day, &month, &year, &second, &minute, &year, name);
```

Answer (score 3):

By checking against it. Try this:

```
int c = sscanf(test.c_str(), "[%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d] INFO - Open [%127[^\]\n]]%*[^\n]\n",
           &day, &month, &year, &second, &minute, &year, name);
```

] has to be escaped, otherwise it would be understood as 'end of delimiter string', which would then be empty...and thereby illegal.

With this addition, it will stop at a linebreak or a ], whatever occurs first.

And of course remove that %c...after all, you don't save it to any variable.

The last addition will read to the next newline character it finds and discard any signs it finds along the way (thus the *).

Comment: If `]` is the first character after the open bracket (or the circumflex in this case), then it is included in the set and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: It sure doesn't hurt to escape it though.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure whats going with the way you match the name, but this works for me:

`int c = sscanf(test.c_str(), "[%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d] INFO - Open [%[^]]"`

This matches anything except the end bracket.

Comment: Since the `name` buffer can only hold 128 characters, use `%127[^]]` instead, otherwise you risk a buffer overflow.

Comment: That would work but leave a trailing `]` in the input file. It needs to be `[%127[^]]]` to get rid of it.